Will not run openshot .3.2.1 on ubuntu 24.04 with raspberry pi 5 with 8 gb ram
chuckw@chuckw-desktop:~$ sudo openshot-qt
[sudo] password for chuckw: 
Loaded modules from: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app:             Thu Sep 19 21:00:28 2024            
INFO app:               Starting new session              
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app:           OpenShot (version 3.2.1-dev)          
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app: openshot-qt version: 3.2.1-dev
INFO app: libopenshot version: 0.3.2
INFO app: platform: Linux-6.8.0-1010-raspi-aarch64-with-glibc2.39
INFO app: processor: aarch64
INFO app: machine: aarch64
INFO app: python version: 3.12.3
INFO app: qt5 version: 5.15.13
INFO app: pyqt5 version: 5.15.10
INFO project_data: Setting profile to HD 720p 30 fps
INFO project_data: Apply default audio playback settings: 48000, 2 channels
INFO app: checking babl_ext_path: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/lib/babl-ext
INFO language: Qt Detected Languages: ['C']
INFO language: LANG Environment Variable: C.UTF-8
INFO language: LOCALE Environment Variable: 
INFO language: OpenShot Preference Language: Default
WARNING app: Displaying 1 startup messages

Message in Box
Wrong Version of libopenshot Detected
Version 0.3.3 is required, but 0.3.2 was detected. Please
update libopenshot or download our latest installer. 
Wanting you to click on OK. Then the message goes away.

Will not run openshot .3.2.1 on Ubuntu 24.04 with raspberry pi 5 with 8 gb ram  with 1TB nvme SSD

How did you install openshot?

Openshot 3.2.1 is not present in official repositories. Please uninstall it (the procedure for uninstallation depends on how you installed it).
The version available on Ubuntu 24.04's official repository is 3.1.1.
Install Openshot from the official repositories with
sudo apt install openshot-qt

and it should automatically configure all the necessary dependencies.
In general, do not install software from outside the official repositories unless it is really necessary to do so.
